# ggplot bars with rainbow colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made a model and calculated varImp() of it. I need to plot varImp() using bars with different colors. I used ggplot and the following codes. However, the bars of my plot always are in grey color. How can I change them to a rainbow with random colors?
These are my codes

```
imp <- varImp(rf_final)
cols = rainbow(45, s=.6, v=.9)[sample(1:45,45)]
ggplot(imp)+ geom_bar(stat="identity")+scale_colour_gradientn(colours=cols)
```

This is my image in grey color.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are not seeing the bars change color with `scale_color_gradientn(...)` is due to two reasons:

1. The color of the bars is mapped to the `fill` aesthetic, not `color` (outline of the bars).  Therefore `scale_fill_gradientn()` would be appropriate.
2. The fill aesthetic is not mapped to anything in your plot code, so the bars are not going to change color until you do.

Here, you want to assign the `fill` aesthetic to be mapped to the same as whatever is mapped to the `x` aesthetic.  I don't know the structure of your dataset, `imp`, so here's an example one:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x=factor(1:45), y=1:45)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=x)) +

  # use geom_col instead of geom_bar(stat="identity")
  # show.legend=F prevents the legend from being drawn
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
      
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rainbow(45))
```

[image]

You can also assign `values= rainbow(45, s=.6, v=.9)[sample(1:45,45)]` to replicate the original plot code from OP; however, the effect will be to scramble the rainbow colors.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ggplot(imp)+ geom_bar(stat="identity")+scale_colour_gradientn(colours = c("red","orange","yellow","green","blue"),
                         values = c(1.0,0.8,0.6,0.4,0.2,0)) )
```

Or

```
ggplot(imp)+ geom_bar(stat="identity")+scale_colour_manual(values = rainbow(8))
```